# npm ERR!? Looks like the react version doesn't match

Tags: reactjs, npm

I don't know what's this mean? How could I fix this?  Thank you.

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@^15.6.2, required by react-dom@15.6.2
```

Comment: What is unclear from that message? `react-dom@15.6.2` requires being installed alongside `react@^15.6.2` (i.e. at least 15.6.2, up to but not including 16.0.0), a requirement that is not being met.

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm install react@15.6.2` to install the required package and satisfy the dependency or just run `npm install` to install `all` required packages